# Is it possible to setup a local artifactory docker repository that points to another instance’s docker repository?

Tags: artifactory

I’m trying to configuring a remote docker repository on my local instance pointing to another hosted by the DevOps team. I tried several URLs including
`https://<user>:<api_token>@<domain>/artifactory/<repo>/` (which lists that instance's docker repo’s contents if I try directly on the browser) but none worked.

Is this possible? If yes, how should I go about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should include the 'api' component as part of the URL. Configure the instance Artifactory (the one that will be proxying another Artifactory Docker repository) with the full URL. This is documented here:

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Docker+Registry#DockerRegistry-DockerRepositoryPathandDomain